# yum update returns kernel error

Tags: fedora, kernel, virtualbox

I want to install virtualbox in fedora20. I have followed the instruction here:

> http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

but when I execute :

> yum update

I get the following error:

> Error: Package: kmod-VirtualBox-3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64-4.3.18-1.fc20.1.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
>   Requires: kernel-uname-r = 3.16.6-200.fc20.x86_64
>   Installed: kernel-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 (@anaconda)
>   kernel-uname-r = 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
>   Installed: kernel-3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
>   kernel-uname-r = 3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64
>   Installed: kernel-3.16.4-200.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
>   kernel-uname-r = 3.16.4-200.fc20.x86_64
>   Available: kernel-debug-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
>   kernel-uname-r = 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64+debug
>   Available: kernel-debug-3.16.4-200.fc20.x86_64 (updates)
>   kernel-uname-r = 3.16.4-200.fc20.x86_64+debug
>   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

How can I solve this problem with the kernel without following the above suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/yum.conf` (or any other yum.conf that your yum might by using. Check for the following line:

```
exclude=kernel*
```

Comment out that line, do a `yum clean all` and try `yum update` again and it should go through fine. This line is asking `yum` to exclude the kernel from getting updated. You are getting that error since kernel is not getting updated, but a package that is depended on the new kernel tries to get updated.